# How to deal with inappropriate comments attached to edits?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, edit-summary

I saw an edit comment being used as a general comment (see comments to the edit number four at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20909102/revisions)).

The edit itself was borderline OK - I wanted to reject it as too minor, but it got approved faster than I clicked [Reject]. However, the comment appears out of place in an edit: it looks like an attempt to circumvent the requirements of the privilege that lets you comment everywhere.

1. Should edits with inappropriate comments be rejected, even if the edit itself is OK?
2. Is it possible to approve the edit, but remove the comment?

Comment: The answers look pretty bad, by the way

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221853/i-dont-think-new-users-are-effectively-taught-how-to-write-good-edit-summaries

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll answer your questions the other way around:

> Is it possible to approve the edit, but remove the comment?

No, not currently. You can add your own comment if you want by improving the suggestion but it won't overwrite the previous comment.

> Should edits with inappropriate comments be rejected, even if the edit itself is OK?

Because of my previous answer this is highly subjective. It depends how inappropriate the content of the comment is. Generally, I'd say that if it's an improvement, it's an improvement. It doesn't matter who's done it and there's no need to reject it.

However, if the comment is definitely inappropriate (i.e. offensive or actual spam) then I don't see how you'd have any choice but to reject the suggestion. In this case it might also be worth flagging a mod to take a look at the user more closely.